# ELM - List to table rows

Tags: elm

In the examples, when mapping a list to html I always see something like

```
ul []
   List.map toHtmlFunction myList
```

But what if the list is only a partial part of the child html elements like

```
...
  table []
        [
        thead []
              [
              th [][text "Product"],
              th [][text "Amount"]
              ],
        List.map toTableRow myList,
        tr []
           [
           td [][text "Total"],
           td [][text toString(model.total)]
           ]

        ]


toTableRow: MyListItem -> Html Msg
toTableRow myListItem =
  tr []
     [
     td[][text myListItem.label],
     td[][text toString(myListItem.price)]
     ]
```

With this code I'm getting

```
The 1st element has this type:

  VirtualDom.Node a

But the 2nd is:

  List (Html Msg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `thead` and `tr` are of type `Html a`, while `List.map` returns a `List (Html a)`, and they can't be combined just by using commas.

You could have a look a the functions for putting list together in the [List package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/List). For example you could do something like

```
table []
    List.concat [
        [ thead []
            [ th [][text "Product"]
            , th [][text "Amount"]
            ]
        ],
        List.map toTableRow myList,
        [ tr []
            [ td [][text "Total"]
            , td [][text toString(model.total)]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Or you could use the `::` operator instead of the `,` -> `[ thead [] [] ] :: List.map`

Comment: @farmio yes, that is another viable option

Comment: Just to note: If you use `::` or similar, you have to use parentheses around the total list, otherwise elm will stop evaluating after the first child/ sublist. So something like `table [] ([ myHeader ] ++ List.map ...)` or `table [] ( myHeader :: List.map ...)`

Answer (score 0):

IMO the cleanest solution lies in @wintvelt's first [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806531/elm-list-to-table-rows#comment63125981_37806939): `table [] ([ myHeader ] ++ List.map ...)`. For new users of elm, this seems the most intuitive. (BTW, I am a new user.)

Essentially, here, the takeaway realization is that the elm compiler doesn't group `table [] [] ++ []` as `table [] ([] ++ [])` (for example). Instead, elm groups it as `(table [] []) ++ []`. This makes sense, if you think about it.

Thus, elm's evaluation of `table [] [] ++ []` produces, at first, something of type `Html msg` (in Elm 0.18). Thereafter, the `++` function balks when it tries to combine that `Html msg` with a `List`.

(Naturally, also, if you try to append a `List` in the wrong way to some of your `Html` attributes, by coding `table [] ++ [] []`, you'll get a similar error message.)

Here's a fleshed out solution, tested with `elm-make 0.18 (elm Platform 0.18.0)`:

```
module Main exposing (main)
import Html exposing (..)

main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
-- MODEL
type alias Model =
    { messages : List String }

init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( Model [], Cmd.none )

-- UPDATE
type Msg
    = None

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg { messages } =
    case msg of
        None ->
            ( Model messages, Cmd.none )

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        []

-- VIEW
type alias MyListItem =
    { label : String
    , price : Float
    }

total : Float
total =
    5.0

myList : List MyListItem
myList =
    [ { label = "labelA", price = 2 }
    , { label = "labelB", price = 3 }
    ]

toTableRow : MyListItem -> Html Msg
toTableRow myListItem =
    tr []
        [ td [] [ text myListItem.label ]
        , td [] [ text (toString myListItem.price) ]
        ]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    table
        []
        ([ thead []
            [ th [] [ text "Product" ]
            , th [] [ text "Amount" ]
            ]
         ]
            ++ List.map toTableRow myList
            ++ [ tr
                    []
                    [ td [] [ text "Total" ]
                    , td [] [ text (toString total) ]
                    ]
               ]
        )
```